# How to simplify this SQL query 2

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL query that I used to use to check user id is exist or not, I am trying to simplify this code, or at least make it better.

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM levels WHERE 
                ('0000000000000.00000000' != (uid1)) AND uid1 IS NOT NULL 
            AND ('0000000000000.00000000' != (uid2)) AND uid2 IS NOT NULL 
            AND ('0000000000000.00000000' != (uid3)) AND uid3 IS NOT NULL 
            AND ('0000000000000.00000000' != (uid4)) AND uid4 IS NOT NULL 
            AND level_unique_id = '$level_unique_id'");
```

And for example if `uid3` is not `null` and not `0000000000000.00000000` , then:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `levels` SET `uid3` = '$UNIQUE_ID'  WHERE `levels`.`level_unique_id` = '$level_unique_id'");
```

How to simplify this SQL query ?

**Description 1:** i know `level_unique_id` but i want to update `uid1` or `uid2` or `uid3` or `uid4` if value `0000000000000.00000000` not in any of the columns

Comment: Adding a unique key which prevents duplication is a better way to do it.

Comment: The mysql functions are depreciated, and not in the current version of PHP. Use either mysqli or PDO functions and use parameterized queries to avoid SQL Injection.

Answer (score 0):

Can u post complete structure of the database. If you need to find the level. Then you should change the query little to get the result.

No need to compare it as string 0.0000000 and etc
**convert it to Int **
SELECT * FROM levels WHERE ( cast (uid1 as Int)!=0) AND uid1 IS NOT NULL AND ( cast (uid1 as Int)!=0) AND uid2 IS NOT NULL AND ( cast (uid1 as Int)!=0) AND uid3 IS NOT NULL AND ( cast (uid1 as Int)!=0) AND uid4 IS NOT NULL AND level_unique_id = '1'